# how can i use vue3 google login with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, vuejs3, passport-google-oauth

i'm trying to use vue3 google login this my component

```
<template>
  <button @click="login">Login Using Google</button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { googleSdkLoaded } from "vue3-google-login";
import axios from "axios";

const login = () => {
  googleSdkLoaded((google) => {
    google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
      client_id: '58730156701-j0squqdlp.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      scope: 'email profile openid',
      callback: (response) => {
        if (response.code) {
          sendCodeToBackend(response.code);
        }
      }
    }).requestCode();
  });
};

const sendCodeToBackend = async (code) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/auth/google/callback', {
      params: { code }
    });
    const { accessToken } = response.data;
  } catch (error) {
  }
};
</script>
```

i get the token but i dont know why the token doesn't reach the backend
[image]
this is my backend

```
app.get(
  '/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] })
);

app.get(
    '/auth/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    (req, res) => {
        console.log(res)
      const code = req.query.code; 
    }
  );
```

this is the error in my nodejs server

```
TokenError: The OAuth client was not found.
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse
```

please how can i go about this

i tried different plugins but non worked